# Lock properties from applying object transformations

Tags: properties

Is there a way to Lock properties from applying object transformations ?

I am using lattice and accidently applying object transformations is causing unwanted results. Please see the Animated GIF of "problem caused by applying object transformations to lattice"

[image: problem caused by applying object transformations to lattice]

Comment: Why are you trying to apply the scale of the cage?

Comment: @Denis I am talking of accidently applying the transform. It would be fool proof if it is locked

Comment: Lock Transform option is not working in this case, wouldn't it be easy just to use CTRL+Z?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be done with lattices.

Also somehow locking the scale to its value and performing scale applying would cause the lattice itself to expand/shrink again (resulting in 2x the original transformation).

Use Mesh Deform instead and keep the scale of that cage at 1. Only this setup will be fool-proof. But Mesh-Deform is not a full supplement for Lattice, depends on what you are doing with it..